# How to find return instruction in memory

Tags: c, debugging, memory, opcode

I have some C code, that calls a function. I'm compiling this code in visual studio on Windows. Is there a straightforward way to view the return instruction (opcode) and the return adress? 
I tried to use the memory window in Visual Studio, but I only see my buffer "blie" and some hexadecimal interpreted memory values. I think CC might be an opcode but I'd like to have a way/software to clearly view the return instruction and the return adress.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int foo(char *);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 1)
        return printf("Supply an argument, dude\n");
    foo(argv[0]);
    return 0;
}

int foo(char *input)
{
    unsigned char buffer[600] = "";

    printf("Adres: %.8X\n", &buffer);
    strcpy(buffer, input);
    return 0;
}
```

[image: memory view]

Comment: In short, no, there's no easy way. You need a full-blown disassembler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return address is located on the stack memory region (pointed to by the `rsp` register, assuming your are on `x86_64`), while the code that performs the function return is located in the code memory region. **If you want to see the return address, stop your process on the `RET` instruction and look at the top of the stack.**

If you only want to look at the generated code you can use a disassembler. As you are using Windows you can try the open source [x64dbg](http://x64dbg.com/). Other options exist, such as [IDA Pro](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/) and you can view a list of others in this question: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1817/is-there-any-disassembler-to-rival-ida-pro

Comment: Thank you for your response @halfr. I tried the following in VS: http://imgur.com/exRiBzR. The ESP is on 00FDF988 when I halted at the RET instruction. Does this mean the return adress is at 00FDF988? If so, I assume its one of the hexadecimal values in memory (a1 15 d5 00), how do these values translate to 00FDF988 ?

Comment: Because `x86` is a [little-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Little-endian) architecture, the return address must be read in "reverse" order compared to how the bytes are stored in memory. In your example, the bytes pointed to by`esp` are `a1 15 d5 00`, therefore the return address is 00D515A1.

Answer (score 1):

Documentation excerpt:

> The RET instruction transfers program control from the procedure currently being
>   executed (the called procedure) back to the procedure that called it (the
>   calling procedure). Transfer of control is accomplished by copying the return 
>   instruction pointer from the stack into the EIP register.

As you can see return address is on the stack so you cannot see that in disassembly.

Regarding finding return instruction - not easy. Most probably you use x86 cpu which is CISC wich has variable length opcodes (in comparison to RISC). This means that in order to find any opcode you must first 'find' all prior to it.

BTW: You can see disassembly of your code in VS.